# CSS border color in percentage

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I'm trying to do something out of the ordinary and haven't got a clue on achieving it.

```css
.border {
  border-color: gold red gold gold;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
.text {
  padding: 60px 10px;
  text-align:center;
}
div {
  border: solid 0.3em;
}
```

```html
<div class="border">
  <p style="">This border color is 25% of the total radius</p>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/eg5rqaLu/2/)

Currently, the red part of the border color is limited to 25% 50% 75% and 100%. How should I go about it so I can set the percentage at my will? Something like 35% or 67% or 90%.

Comment: You can't. Not like that anyways.

Comment: Because an element only has four sides. Anything other than 25%, 50%, 75%, or 100% would require something else like canvas.

Comment: There are only four borders for any element, as all the elements are technically rectangles (or four sided figures). So, it would be better if you can mask something and position them, at the same place.

Comment: You can use SVG path for that

Comment: or you can use circliful ;)

Comment: In addition to all those that I linked in my earlier comment (see Linked section on right hand side), you can also use gradients like here - http://codepen.io/hari_shanx/pen/ZQbpap. It is upto you to choose whichever one is better for your use-case. SVG is generally the recommended option.

Comment: Thanks guys for your input. Thought there's a way but anyways :)